# strict evaluation of integer accumulator

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strictness

Here is a classic first attempt at a custom `length` function:

```
length1    []  = 0
length1 (x:xs) = 1 + length1 xs
```

And here is a tail-recursive version:

```
length2 = length2' 0 where
    length2' n    []  = n
    length2' n (x:xs) = length2' (n+1) xs
```

However, `(n+1)` will not be evaluted strictly, but instad Haskell will create a thunk, right?

Is this a correct way to prevent the creation of the thunk, thus forcing strict evaluation of `(n+1)`?

```
length3 = length3' 0 where
    length3' n    []  = n
    length3' n (x:xs) = length3' (n+1) $! xs
```

How would I achieve the same effect with `seq` instead of `$!`?

Comment: If you turn on optimization you don't have to do anything since strictness analysis can determine that the definition is strict in `n`.

Comment: That said, exactly what happens with that strictness information depends on the type.  If you use `Int` it will certainly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way now to write it would be as:

```
length3 :: [a] -> Int
length3 = go 0
    where
        go :: Int -> [a] -> Int
        go n []     = n
        go n (x:xs) = n `seq` go (n+1) xs
```

Namely, as a fold over the list strict in the accumulator.
GHC yields the direct translation to Core:

```
Main.$wgo :: forall a_abz. GHC.Prim.Int# -> [a_abz] -> GHC.Prim.Int#
Main.$wgo =
  \ (n :: GHC.Prim.Int#) (xs :: [a_abz]) ->
    case xs of
      [] -> n
      _ : xs -> Main.$wgo a (GHC.Prim.+# n 1) xs
```

Showing that it is unboxed (and thus strict) in the accumulator.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's quite right--`$!` is strict in its second argument, so you're just forcing the list and not the accumulator.

You can get the right strictness using seq something like this:

```
let n' = n + 1 in n' `seq` length3' n' xs
```

I think a more readable version would use bang patterns (a GHC extension):

```
length3' !n (x:xs) = ...
```